# Cannot use Async/Await in a Serverless NodeJS Function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, serverless

I'm new to Serverless with NodeJS, I'm trying to use an Async function to hash a password and perform some stuff in a database, the problem is that when I declare the functions async I always get this error:

[image]

But if I remove the async keyword here:

```
module.exports.login = async (event, context, callback) => {
```

the function runs properly, but of course I won't be able to use promises within the function.

This is an endpoint, to make API calls.

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const dataBase = require('./utils/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const encryptPassword = async (plainPassword) => {
   const saltRounds = 10;
   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds);
   return hashedPassword;
};

module.exports.login = async (event, context, callback) => {
   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
   const connect = dataBase.connectToDatabase();
   const newPassword = await encryptPassword('test');

   console.log(newPassword);

   connect.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
         console.error(error);
         callback(null, {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
               error: JSON.stringify(error),
               message: 'Internal Server Error Booh!',
            }),
         });
      }
      if (results) {
         callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
               error: results,
               message: 'No Error',
            }),
         });
      }
   });
};
```

Here my db connection and config:

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const isDev = true;

// Create mySQL Connection
const connectToDatabase = () => {
   const pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: isDev ? process.env.DATABASE_HOST_DEV : process.env.DATABASE_HOST_PROD,
      user: isDev ? process.env.DATABASE_USER_DEV : DATABASE_USER_PROD,
      password: isDev ? process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD_DEV : DATABASE_PASSWORD_PROD,
      database: isDev ? process.env.DATABASE_DATABASE_DEV : DATABASE_DATABASE_PROD,
      multipleStatements: true,
   });
   return pool;
};

exports.connectToDatabase = connectToDatabase;
exports.mysql = mysql;
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

The purpose of all this, it's because I'm learning serverless.

All this will end up in an AWS Lambda with an endpoint using API Gateway.

So, when you call this endpoint, you will be sending some params to register/login into an app.

I need to use async/await because if you register an account, the password needs to be hashed and then store into a database or if you login, the password will need to be compared, both of these actions are asynchronous ones.

That's why I need the endpoint to be an async function.

**EDIT 2:**

Reading this post: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-dev-plugin/issues/160

As Phil mention, async and callback shouldn't be used togehter, so I modified my code like this, and same error:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const dataBase = require('./utils/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const encryptPassword = async (plainPassword) => {
   const saltRounds = 10;
   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds);
   return hashedPassword;
};

module.exports.login = async (event, context, callback) => {
   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
   const connect = dataBase.connectToDatabase();
   const newPassword = await encryptPassword('test');

   console.log(newPassword);

   connect.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
         console.error(error);
         return {
            error: 'some error to test',
         };
      }
      if (results) {
         return {
            body: 'someBody',
         };
      }
   });
};
```

**FINAL FUNCTIONAL CODE:**

In case any wonder how to make these queries as promises, here's my approach, hope it helps anyone out there struggling with the same.

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });

const dataBase = require('./utils/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const encryptPassword = async (plainPassword) => {
   const saltRounds = 10;
   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds);
   return hashedPassword;
};

module.exports.login = async (event, context, callback) => {
   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
   const connect = dataBase.connectToDatabase();

   const hashedPassword = await encryptPassword('test');

   console.log(hashedPassword);

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connect.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, result) => {
         if (error) {
            reject(
               callback(null, {
                  statusCode: 500,
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                     error: JSON.stringify(error),
                     message: 'Internal Server Error Booh!',
                  }),
               })
            );
         }
         if (result) {
            resolve(
               callback(null, {
                  statusCode: 200,
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                     data: result,
                     message: 'No Error',
                  }),
               })
            );
         }
      });
   });
};
```

Regards.

Comment: `encryptPassword` doesn't appear to be async so why are you _awaiting_ it? If anything was going to be asynchronous, it would be `dataBase.connectToDatabase()` but you haven't shown that code

Comment: You are right, I've updated the code, hashing a password must be an async/await function, same issue still.

Comment: it is not totally clear what the use case is here - is this being called externally as an api or internally on the app?

Comment: This will be an API call (It's an endpoint), externally.

Comment: Ok thanks - and this is mentioned as 'serverless' but that is just an architecture decision - this code is designed to run on a server either way so that does not have bearing. Are you using a framework like express? It will help answer probably where you want to go with this

Comment: Understood, i've updated my post, I hope y made myself clear, if not, let me know.

Comment: Why is `connectToDatabase` async?

Comment: My bad, that's an error from my side, it shouldn't be async.

Comment: Got it, post updated again.

Comment: what about using promise with async?

Comment: The real problem here is the `mysql` library. I strongly suggest moving to a promise-based API like `mysql2`

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much for your effort and time. I'm going to use a promise-based API like the one you suggest.

Comment: Look around, there's probably something even nicer than `mysql2` these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html), it doesn't look like you should be mixing `async` with the `callback` arg. Just use one or the other, not both.

You could migrate to the `mysql2` library so you can use promises or stick with the one you've got and use `encryptPassword("test").then()` instead of `await`

```js
// no async
module.exports.login = (event, context, callback) => {
  // remove this, you don't want it
  // context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const connect = dataBase.connectToDatabase();
  encryptPassword("test").then(newPassword => { // use .then()
    console.log(newPassword);

    // callback APIs are a pain, recommend migrating to mysql2 and use promises
    connect.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return callback(null, {
          statusCode: 500,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            error: JSON.stringify(error),
            message: 'Internal Server Error Booh!',
          }),
        });
      }
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: results, // error?
          message: 'No Error',
        }),
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This works properly, I think the real issue here is the mysql library. Maybe It would be a good idea to move to a promise-based API